# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-405

The message that comes up when I hit submit. 
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, But can you tell me, how can i do this?

Comment: For a start, what web server are you using?

Comment: You will find the form at
http://mycoindia.co.in
Click on feedback.
Then Click on the submit button and the error message appears.

Comment: that does not answer the question as to what web server you are using.

Comment: sry i dont know, i dont have much info. about the same

Comment: I caused this error by using Google Postman to test a Web API and sent the URL as GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your web server to allow POST to that URL.